# Can SendGrid Domain Authentication records be deleted after verification?

Tags: dns, sendgrid

The Domain Authentication process requires creating three cname DNS records. Something like:

em1234.example.com

s1._domainkey.example.com

s1._domainkey.example.com

Our website domain is moving to another Azure directory, and so I have to set up a new SendGrid account.  The previous account already has those records setup. The number in the first record is different, but the last two are the same. In order to verify the domain in the new account, I have to set them up again, and the values will change. If I set up the new values, will the old account still be able to send email?  The new site is not yet launching, but I'd like to have it all set up and tested beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the CNAME records that you set up through domain authentication allow for SendGrid to handle and keep up to date the requirements for [SPF](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/spf-records) and [DKIM](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/dkim-records). So, if you were to create a new SendGrid account and change the `s1._domainkey.example.com` record for your domain to the settings for the new account, then your emails from your old account might start being rejected or failing SPF and DKIM checks.

You might consider setting up your emails under a subdomain while you move between accounts to avoid messing with the main domain's DNS records. Or you could move your existing mails to be sent out over a subdomain and then set up the main domain on your new account.

For more in depth support with this, I recommend checking with [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

I just learned from SendGrid support that you can set up CNAME records with a different prefix than s1 and s2 by choosing a custom DKIM selector: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication#using-a-custom-dkim-selector

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the DKIM (by replacing the default "**s1**" / "**s2**" prefix with any three permitted characters of your choice.

**s1**._domainkey.example.com  --> **SG1**._domainkey.example.com
**s2**._domainkey.example.com  --> **SG2**._domainkey.example.com

In the above example, I have replaced it with **SG1** & **SG2** instead of S1 and S2. You can do this by following the steps below,

•   Log into the SendGrid account. 
•   Go to "Settings" 
•   then "Sender authentication" 
•   from here you will go to "authenticate your domain" 
•   On the first page you will fill out the Domain host information and click on next.
•   Here you will enter your domain information and click on "Advance Settings" 
•   Here on "Use a custom DKIM selector" you can use any 3 letter combination to differentiate the multiple SendGrid accounts. 
•   Click on next 
•   the CNAME records will be created, and you will go ahead and add them to your domain host. 
•   Once the CNAME records added you can click on verify on the top right of the records.